# Execute a function before and after a request finishes in RestKit

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, restkit, restful-url

I want to call a function to start a spinner before every request is made and stop it after every request (fail or success) finishes in Restkit. How would I achieve this without having to manually call my spinner start/stop function before and after every time I use the `RKObjectManager` sharedManger? Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

So write an intermediate function that takes the request as a parameter along with a completion handler. It would start the spinner spinning, invoke the request, then stop the spinner and invoke the completion handler.

I haven't used RestKit, so I can't be more specific than that, but that approach should work.